# Big O: What is the name for the complexity O(a * b)?

Tags: time-complexity, big-o

I am new to studying the Big O notation and have thought of this question. What is the name for the complexity O(a * b)? Is it linear complexity? polynomial? or something else. The code for the implementation is below.

```js
function twoInputsMult(a, b) {
    for (let i = 0; i < a; i++) {
        for (let j = 0; j < b; j++) {
            // do something
        }
    }
}
```

Edit: According to the course I'm going through, it is not n^2 or quadratic since it uses two different numbers for the loops. Refer to the image below [image: An image that says O(a*b) is not n^2]

Comment: It used 2 `for loops`, so it should be `O(n^2)`

Comment: @AnhPC03 I edited the question regarding your response.

Comment: @AnhPC03 it is not. It does not have quadratic growth. For `a = 10` and `b = 10` the result is 100 operations, however, each of this can change individually, for `a = 11` and `b = 10` you do not get 121 operations. Two loops *over the same `n`* give you quadratic growth. Because literally for every `n` you do `n` operations. Evidently, not the case here.

Comment: @VLAZ Hey dude, thanks for the response. May I just ask if you know what O(a * b) is called (like linear, quadratic etc.). Or maybe it also resolves to O(n) where n is a because a >= b which I got from something similar from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27177838/if-a-b-then-oab-oa). I really don't know

Comment: I'm not sure what the name of it is. `O(a*b)` and `O(a+b)` crop up fairly often but I'm not sure what their actual classification is.

Comment: @VLAZ Alright, thanks again for the response.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*O(ab)* is just *O(ab)*. Technically, *ab* is a [multivariate polynomial](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/MultivariatePolynomial.html) of 2<sup>nd</sup> degree. But this is not equivalent to a quadratic polynomial, such as *a<sup>2</sup>*.

If you know more about *a* and *b*, you may be able to deduce more about their relationship. For instance, if *a = O(b)*, then *O(ab) = O(b<sup>2</sup>)*, which is quadratic. On the other hand, if *a* is a constant, then we can reduce it to *O(b)*, which is linear.

Notice, by the way, that *O(a + b*) is just *O(max(a, b))*.

And if the real world interests you, I might also mention that both of these complexity classes show up a lot e.g. in graph theory, where we have the number of vertices *|V|* and the number of edges *|E|*, and typically *|E| = O(|V|<sup>2</sup>)* but not necessarily. For instance, [Depth-first search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search) has a time complexity of *O(|V| + |E|)*, which just means that it is linear in terms of whichever there is more of: vertices or edges.